# Session Variable not holding values in production in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, session

I have a Session variable holding a boolean value. It works just fine in on my development machine and my development server. When I move my code to production it no longer works.

It doesn't matter if I'm using a cookieless session either, so it can't be a timeout issue or a cookie issue.

It happens on all modern browsers.

I'm using the Response.Redirect overload where the endResponse parameter is set to false.

The machine is not in a webfarm.

Session storage is to my knowledge InProc, it is not in SQL Server.

The session variable holds the boolean variable at least once, because I print it out in a label on the page following my setting of the variable and the Response.Redirect. But afterward it gets set back to NULL, it does not do this in development.

Its all the same code, but the IIS settings might be different on production, I just don't know where to look.

Comment: Is your production environment in a web farm?

Comment: What session storage method are you using in production?

Comment: Its not in a webfarm, and to my knowledge the session storage method is InProc. The IIS server does run other websites that don't use a Session by design. IIS was configured by those same people.

Comment: To give this question a sense of closure, since I doubt I'll ever accept an answer here, I ended up setting up an entirely new server to correct the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yikes this could turn into a nightmare of a problem.

Do you have a completely independent and clean machine you can deploy your project to and see if you can replicate the behavior on another IIS that is in a known state?

Do you have the ability to just reimage the server?

Check settings on the server's applicationHost.config and machine.config to see if the session is set to use InProc or Sql based session persistence. If it's sql based is the database screwed up?

Assuming the session is InProc like you expect, is IIS reseting constantly? Do trace logging of your application start and end events.

Comment: I opened up machine.config and applicationHost.config and searched for Session in those files and everything looks benign. The session is not sql based. I have deployed it to my development machine, I configured that machine so its pretty default, but it doesn't have a domain name attached. I will look into the Application Start and End events logging.

Comment: If you're inproc and losing session values that most often involves some sort of issue with reclcying or crashing

Comment: Well thanks for that, unfortunately I don't know how to fix it without creating another server instance. I was hoping there was some setting I should look out for. The guys that set up the IIS originally were very Session averse, and nothing they created *really* needed one.

Comment: Were able to verify whether the app is recycling continuously? Because if you see that occurring there's more that can be explored on that front. Getting a clean independent server would really give you the information you need on whether it's your application or the server configuration however.

Comment: I was not. I put some logging in the Global.asax file for all of the events (App Start, App End, App Err, Session Start, Session End). The Application was not throwing any extra starts or stops or any errors. The session values were being lost after what seems like a normal app start and session start, only throwing the end events after a period of idle time.

Answer (score 1):

Is your application being called by an iframe or somethnig? I had this problem once, Icouldn't find a solution, I'm still looking for one
I solved this problem integrating the application in the same server as the application who loaded our app in an iframe.

Hope it helps you.